# Synapse Spark Pool hung on Provisioning State: Delete Error

Tags: azure-synapse

I would like to delete a spark pool in my workspace but any attempt to do so results in a generic error appearing: `An error has occurred while deleting the resource.`

If I attempt to edit the pool in any way I'm presented with this error:

`Target Spark pool specified in Spark job definition is not in succeeded state. Current state: DeleteError`

I am able to start a notebook session on the pool, but that does not affect the provisioning state. Any ideas as to how I can get my pool back to the `succeeded` provisioning state?

Comment: Do you have any notebooks connected to that Spark Pool?  If so, repoint them to another Spark Pool and save / commit them.

Comment: Thank you, @wBob that did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From wBob's comment:

`Do you have any notebooks connected to that Spark Pool? If so, repoint them to another Spark Pool and save / commit them.`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).